# Excel offsets to suit complex autofill scenario

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Having some trouble with off setting cells in order to use the auto fill option in excel rather than entering cell formula manually which is what I'm doing at the moment.

Here is an example of what Im trying to achieve

IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$19),'Item Breakdowns'!A25,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$19),'Item Breakdowns'!A26,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$19),'Item Breakdowns'!A27,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$19),'Item Breakdowns'!A28,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$19),'Item Breakdowns'!A29,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$19),'Item Breakdowns'!A30,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$19),'Item Breakdowns'!A31,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$19),'Item Breakdowns'!A32,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$19),'Item Breakdowns'!A33,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$19),'Item Breakdowns'!A34,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$36),'Item Breakdowns'!A42,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$36),'Item Breakdowns'!A43,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$36),'Item Breakdowns'!A44,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$36),'Item Breakdowns'!A45,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$36),'Item Breakdowns'!A46,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$36),'Item Breakdowns'!A47,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$36),'Item Breakdowns'!A48,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$36),'Item Breakdowns'!A49,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$36),'Item Breakdowns'!A50,"")
IF(COUNTIF(Power!$A:$A,'Item Breakdowns'!$B$36),'Item Breakdowns'!A51,"")

This list of formulas starts in cell A1 and continues down to cell A20.

Basically I want to try and enter a formula in cell A1 that allows me to autofill down to cell A20 and beyond whilst keeping my layout and cell increments.

From the list above I hope it shows that what I need to achieve in the first part of the formula is to hold 'Item Breakdowns'!$B$19 for the first 10 cells then increase it by +17 cells to 'Item Breakdowns'!$B$36 then continue that for 10 more cells, then repeat this process.

The second part of the formula I need to start at 'Item Breakdowns'!A25 and increase by 1 cell each time through the first 10 cells.
A25
A26
A27
A28
A29
A30
A31
A32
A33
A34
Then increase by +8 cells and continue again with the 1 cell increase
A42
A43
A44
A45
A46
A47
A48
A49
A50
A51

I cant work this one out and Im not sure that it is achievable. Im able to use some auto fill but have to stop each time because of the increment jumps shown.
I have a lot of data to enter through this method and normally I would live with this style if it was only a small amount of data.

Hopefully someone has an idea of what I can try hear. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will iterate as you drag it down.

The first reference B19 will increase by 17 every ten rows.

The second reference A25 will iterate by one, but will jump 8 every ten rows.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Power!A:A,INDEX('Item Breakdowns'!B:B,19+(QUOTIENT(ROW(1:1)-1,10)*17))),INDEX('Item Breakdowns'!A:A,ROW(25:25)+(QUOTIENT(ROW(1:1)-1,10)*7)))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks so much for you help!